# Fill 24 hours of data into five years of hourly dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 5 years worth of hourly data.

```
import datetime as dt
StartDate = dt.date(2008,1,1)
EndDate = dt.date(2015,8,1)
dfIndex = pd.date_range(start=StartDate,end=EndDate,freq='H')
dfColumns = ['C1','C2','C2']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dfIndex,columns=dfColumns)
```

I have another dataframe for just 24 hours.

```
dfTemp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(60,100,(24,3)),index=pd.date_range(StartDate,periods=24,freq='H'),columns='C1 C2 C3'.split())
```

I would like to fill each day of the first dataframe with the data from the second dataframe. Instead of looping through each day .. is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can repeat a list by using the * operator, for example

```
print([1,2,3]*2)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

So for your example, you could repeat your sample data `len(df)/24` times and set it into your original dataframe using `iloc`, (i've had to select `iloc[:-1,:]` since your index actually contains one extra time point on the last day):

```
df.iloc[:-1,:] = dfTemp.values.tolist()*(int(len(df)/24))
df.head()
Out[198]: 
                     C1  C2  C2
2008-01-01 00:00:00  98  88  79
2008-01-01 01:00:00  79  72  72
2008-01-01 02:00:00  67  72  70
2008-01-01 03:00:00  61  85  73
2008-01-01 04:00:00  81  66  92
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
df.combineAdd(dfTemp)
```

but this will fill only the first day in your case not all the days , I'm not sure if you want to fill all data frame values from `df` or if you want to fill only the matched values from both data frames , this shall work if you want to match only the matches indices from both data frames .

Comment: I want to fill all the days with the same values from dfTemp.